# How to retrieve display url instead of t.co in twitter widget script

Tags: jquery, twitter, short-url

I googled and found many articles on twitter widgets with jquery. They all seem to fetch links as t.co. But as I use my own short url service, I want to retrieve the exact short url and not t.co.

Here is a sample tweet:
http://twitter.com/sosyalmedyaco/status/360771636821098498
I want the widget to display "smco.me/jsqurfe".

Here is the code I use:

```
    function addlinks(data) {
    //Add link to all http:// links within tweets
     data = data.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, 
  function(url) {
        return '<a href="'+url+'" >'+url+'</a>';
    });

    //Add link to @usernames used within tweets
    data = data.replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
        return '<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'" style="font-weight:lighter;" target="_blank">'+reply.charAt(0)+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });
    //Add link to #hastags used within tweets
    data = data.replace(/\B#([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
        return '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q='+reply.substring(1)+'" style="font-weight:lighter;" target="_blank">'+reply.charAt(0)+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });
    return data;
}
```

Google gave me this answer but I couldn't apply it to my code. http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/08/twitters-shortened-links/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Twitter will always give you a `t.co` domain from their tweets for many reasons. But you mention "as I use my own short url service"?

Comment: I want the widget to display the url as here (smco.me/jsqurfe): https://twitter.com/sosyalmedyaco/status/360771636821098498